# How to find last value of a List in file.txt if first value match the entered data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple car rental system to check price of a car.

This is the `Available Vehicles.txt` In which the 3rd row is the car price.

```
RegNumber | Car Name | Price | Transmission Type
```

```
H4E-11,Toyota,66,Automatic Transmission
X11-11,Volkswagen,62,Automatic Transmission
JBA-123,Ibiza,65,Automatic Transmission
MDZ-A1A,Kodiaq,71,Automatic Transmission
```

I want to loop through the first row and if the registration number matches the entered registration number it goes through the line and checks the price in the third column

I have a function that asks user to enter his/her car registration number it then checks if the registration number is available in the first row of a file.

```py
def returnCar():
    # Ask registration number of car to rent
        regNumber = str(input("Please enter Registration Number of Car: "))

 # Check if Car is  in the system

        regNumbers = []  # List of registration number [H4E-11, X11-11, JBA-123, MDZ-A1A]

        with open("../AvailableVehicles.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                for data in f:
                        regRow = str(data.split(",")[0])
                        regNumbers += [regRow]   # append registration number to the list
        if regNumber in regNumbers:
                # get price from equivalent row
```

I want to print something like:

```
Please enter Registration Number of Car: H4E-11
The price is: 66 dollars
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't parse manually csv files, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

regNumber = input("Please enter Registration Number of Car: ")

with open('AvailableVehicles.txt') as f:
    # load file lazily
    data = csv.reader(f)

    # let's use a generator to stop on the first match
    price = next((row[2] for row in data if row[0] == regNumber), None)
    if price:
        print(f'The price is: {price}')
    else:
        print(f'Registration number not found')
```

Alternative using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), an advantage would be to compute once the prices to be able to map any registration number repeatedly without parsing the file again:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('AvailableVehicles.txt', names=['RegNumber', 'Car Name', 'Price', 'Transmission Type'])
prices = df.set_index('RegNumber')['Price']

# this could be in a loop
regNumber = input("Please enter Registration Number of Car: ")

if regNumber in prices.index:
    print(f'The price is: {prices.get(regNumber)}')
else:
    print('Registration number not found')
```

Output:

```
Please enter Registration Number of Car: H4E-11
The price is: 66
```

Comment: @Alexander no [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns a generator, the first example only reads the full file if there is no match, with the provided example this would read only **one** line. Then I have to disagree about the "*complexity*". The module loading time is insignificant compared to the benefits of not having to parse the file manually. Parsing CSV is full of pitfalls, having a simple file is no reason not to learn good practices, this is time saved in the future.

Comment: Sorry thoght your were using list comprehension in your fist example... I guess we will have to disagree on the complexity issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index` method to find out which row matched the registration number then you would have to re-open your file and loop to that line and get the price.

It would be much easier to get the price by comparing the registration number while you are looping through the file the first time. Then if you find a match you can just print the price immediate and break out of the loop, avoiding iterating the remaining lines needlessly

For example:

```
def returnCar():
    regNumber = str(input("Please enter Registration Number of Car: "))
    with open("../AvailableVehicles.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for data in f:
            line = data.split(',')
            if line[0] == regNumber:
                price = line[2]
                print(f'The price is: ${price} dollars')
                break
```